# how to set nvd3 tooltip boundary

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to make this tool tip's position
[image]
relative to the parent div
this is how I am implementing the web page:

```
<div id="parent">
        <div id="chart">
            <svg style="height:500px">
            </svg>
        </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
#parent
{
     margin-top:300px;
     border: solid blue;
     height: 600px;
}
#chart
{
    border: solid red;
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
svg
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I found `chartContainer` in the nvd3.js file, but I couldn't edit it.
So are there possible solutions ?

Comment: The tooltip is positioned so that it is over the associated data.  Howe do you want that to change?

Comment: Could you setup a jsFiddle?

Comment: Can't you just fix the problem by setting the gravity to have it rendered on the bottom of the point? (check tooltip.js gravity). Otherwise you can pass functions for positioning the tooltip.

Comment: [Similar Question][1]refer to this question 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571803/nvd3-js-tooltip-position-with-multiple-charts