# wrong position of Tooltip in lineChart Nvd3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, nvd3.js, linechart

I have a page that contains multiple graphs made ​​with NVD- chart.js . the graphs are placed in a dashboard , so each part of the dashboard contains a graph. This dashboard contains two line charts. The problem is that the tooltip of the second line-chart  is badly placed in the left, so it's far from its line-chart.

I tried many codes like:

1)

```
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.chartContainer(d3.select('#chart_ligne svg'));
```

i want whith this line of code to force the container of the tooltip but there is no changes

2)

```
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.position({"left":50})
```

iwant with this line of code to fix the tooltip in a fix position to be in her line chart but there is no changes.

3)

```
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.gravity('s')
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.gravity('n')
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.gravity('w')
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.gravity('e')
```

There is no changes.
Please someone have an idea and help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29576987/5100729), but it not work.

Finally, I solved the problem by updating d3.js to the latest version (3.5.16) with the 1.8.1 version of nvd3.